# Task Queue solution?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

I never used task queue before. 
I'm having a problem trying to get a report of all of my contacts from the datastore.

The code is:

```
allContactos=db.GqlQuery("select * from contactsDB").run(batch_size=1000)
for contactN in allContactos:
    ... (here I put all the fields in csv format)
```

The problem is that I'm getting a "500 Server Error" because of the massive quantity of contacts.

My question is, is it a good aproach to try to solve this with task queue?
can you give me some tip to segregate that query in many tasks?

Regards!

Comment: if you always do operation among all entries in a datastore model, you can use mapreduce.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split your query in many tasks. You can start one task. If this task takes more than 10 minutes, you will have to use a [backend](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/) to run this task.

You will to either email the file to a user when a task is finished, or create a link in your app/website to download this file when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How do I know when the task is finished? and how can I create a link to obtain the result of the task?

Comment: Note that if it takes over 10min you dont necessarily need a backend. Assuming a huge list you could query with pagination (page tokens) and have one task queue after the other, each does one page. But the output would have to be something like a drive text file and you keep appending to it.

Comment: Task chaining: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/03/Task-Queue-task-chaining-done-right

Comment: Your task finishes when the last line of code in it is executed. You can send yourself (or a user) an email when the task finishes writing a file, for example. As for the link, your app can periodically query the server to see if the file is available. When it finds a file, it can display a link to retrieve it.